# Dynamically create Barcharts for distinct column values using loop in Python-Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, bokeh

I have a data frame with a column name "Type" which gets categorical values like A,B,C etc. This column gets values dynamically and the distinct/unique values can change from time to time.

> **Eg. Data set Image**:

[image]

I want to run the following code to create bar charts (using Bokeh visualization library) dynamically for each of the distinct values in "Type" column.

Here is what I am currently running by manually slicing the data for each value in "Type"

> Lets say "df" is name of the data frame containing rows only for "Type" =A

```
source_df  = ColumnDataSource(df)

TOOLTIPS = [ ("Month : ", "@Month"),
             (" Aggregated Metric1 : ", "@Metric1{ 0.0 a}") ]

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips =  TOOLTIPS

pYOY = figure(x_range=df['Month'], y_range=(0, 100000), plot_height=300,plot_width=1000, 
           toolbar_location=None, tools = "box_select, box_zoom , wheel_zoom,reset")

pYOY.vbar(x=dodge('Month', 0, range=pYOY.x_range), top='Metric1', width=0.2, source=source_df,
       color="#c9d9d3", legend=("# Rev"))

pYOY.tools.append(hover)
pYOY.yaxis.axis_label = "Rev"
pYOY.xaxis.axis_label = "Month"
```

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: So you already have the code to generate the bar charts, but need help to split the data frames by type, right?

Comment: Hi @BurningKarl , I need to in a way automate the code above for creating barcharts for all the "type" without manually identifying what all "type" are available,which varies with data pull at different time periods. Splitting the data is not a problem but how to pass those without any manual intervention into the barchart code above.

Comment: Are you trying to get one plot with multiple groups? Or literally entire separate plots, one for each group?

Comment: @BhavukSingh Have you tried `source_df['Type'].unique()`? This gives a numpy array of all the unique types in the Type column. Then you can loop over these values and use `source_df.loc[source_df['Type'] == current_type]` to get the rows of this type.

Comment: Hi @bigreddot , I was looking to create entire separate plots but I am open to explore one plot with multiple groups.

Comment: @BurningKarl, I haven't tried that yet but will give it a try :) Thanks!